# adding filter to pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I would like to add a filtering condition to a pivot table, like this:

(Select the values of v2 equal to 'A')

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['v1'],columns=['v2'=='A'],values=['v3'],aggfunc='count')
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 10):

This is an extension of [Grr's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5061557/grr) answer.

Using their suggestion:

```
pd.pivot_table(df[df.v3 == some_value], index='v1', columns='A', values='v3', aggfunc='count')
```

Produces an error:

> "TypeError: pivot_table() got multiple values for argument 'values'"

I made a slight tweak, and it works for me:

```
df[df.v3 == some_value].pivot_table(index='v1', columns='A', values='v3', aggfunc='count')
```

For adding multiple filters:
Use **&**, **|** operators with a set of () to specify the priority.
Using **and**,**or** results in an error.

```
df[(df.v3 == some_value) & (df.v4 == some_value)].pivot_table(index='v1', columns='A', values='v3', aggfunc='count')
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to filter by columns you could just pass a single column name, or list of names. For example:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='v1', columns='A', values='v3', aggfunc='count')
pd.pivot_table(df, index='v1', columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], values='v3', aggfunc='count')
```

If you want to filter by values you would just filter the DataFrame. For example:

```
pd.pivot_table(df[df.v3 == some_value], index='v1', columns='A', values='v3', aggfunc='count')
```

Comment: Can I do this for two separate some_values, and add them together?  I have the below working correctly for "Civilian Labor", but I want to do the same for "Labor Overhead" and add them together for a new column called "Total Labor."

'Labor_Table = CJI3[CJI3['Cost Element LANT Category Name'] == "Civilian Labor"].pivot_table(values=['Charge Amount'],index=['Project Unit ID','Fiscal Year'],columns=['Cost Element LANT Category Name'],aggfunc=sum,fill_value=0,dropna=True)'

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `where` condition as well here:

```
df.where([df.v3 == some_value]).pivot_table(index='v1', columns='A', values='v3', aggfunc='count')
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be useful if you need to filter for more than one value:

```
mask = df['v2'].isin(['A', 'B', 'C'])
table = df[mask].pivot_table(
        values='v3', 
        index=['v1'],
        columns=['v2'], 
        aggfunc='count', 
    )
```